# Register a custom chart type in highcharts without rebuilding from source?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to create a custom chart type in Highcharts. To be more precise: A custom variant of "organization" similar to how "organization" is a custom variant of "sankey".

Is this possible in a simple HTML/JavaScript project?

One of the issues I encountered: The OrganizationSeries sources access the function `SeriesRegistry.registerSeriesType(...)`, but that does not seem to be exposed in a distribution package. I can see the examples using `H.wrap(...)`, but I don't see how this can be used to create a custom chart type. Am I missing something obvious?

If this is not possible, I'll look into building a custom Highcharts module, but I was hoping for some exploration where I could spare me the setup of all the required items for building Highcharts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the old way of adding new series types, similar to [creating new indicators](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators#5-custom-column-indicator). The old factory is the `seriesType` function:

```
// type, parent, options, seriesProto, pointProto
H.seriesType('custom-organization', 'organization', {...}, {...});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hLjeuyzn/

Or the new way with classes:

```
(function (H) {
  class CustomOrganiation extends H.seriesTypes.organization {

 }

  H.Series.registerType("custom-organization", CustomOrganiation);
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-butterfly-6-6emo0w?file=/src/index.js

**Organization series source code:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Series/Organization/OrganizationSeries.ts